# my code works for single input but whn i use lambda it doesnt work?

Tags: python, pandas

I change the field of 'date' to datetime in order to calculate the difference between their cells and 'today'

`df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='ignore')`

so i can try below code for several random indexes such as below:

`pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - df['date'][1003]`

Timedelta('2598 days 00:00:00')

as you see it works.

but when i run this code i got error:

`df['Diff']=df['date'].agg(lambda x:pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()-x)`

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

> how can I recognize bad dates? i need all of dates with any NaT.

Filter missing values `NaT` generated if not match pattern `%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S` or if datetime not exist like `2020-02-30 12:02:10`:

```
out = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce').isna(), 'date']
```

Problem is with `errors='ignore'` it working different like you think.

It return same ouput if at least one wrong datetime, so is possible get mixed datetimes with strings or only string column (like original column `date`).

If need datetime column need replace bad dates to `NaT` by:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')

df['Diff'] = pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - df['date']
```

Comment: how can I recognize bad dates? i need all of dates with any ```NaT```. shall I fix it in my excel dataset manually?

Comment: @hamideh - added to answer.

Comment: woul you please clear how to fix the ```out```, i should change them to ```%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S```? how?

Comment: @hamideh - what is `out` ?

Comment: i mean ```out = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce').isna(), 'date']```

Comment: I know, but I have no idea what is `print (out)`, because no your data

Comment: ```5      NaT
6      NaT
7      NaT
11     NaT
13     NaT
        ..
1049   NaT
1050   NaT
1051   NaT
1052   NaT
1053   NaT
Name: date, Length: 654, dtype: datetime64[ns]'''

Comment: @hamideh - do you run it before `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: no, this is the code before that: ```5       2014-09-20 00:00:00
6       2014-09-16 00:00:00
7       2014-09-13 00:00:00
11      2014-09-27 00:00:00
13      2014-09-16 00:00:00
               ...         
1049    2015-09-16 00:00:00
1050    2015-10-13 00:00:00
1051    2015-10-13 00:00:00
1052    2015-10-22 00:00:00
1053    2015-10-20 00:00:00
Name: date, Length: 654, dtype: object```

Comment: @hamideh - yop, ouput is expected, because `'%Y-%d-%m` means `YYYY-DD-MM` and it means `20` cannot be month, so returned like error `2014-09-20 00:00:00`. Maybe need change `%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S` to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` swapped `m, d`